# gatsby-source-cloudinary: How to add both video and image into the resourcetype tag?

Tags: gatsby

I've only saw posts putting in either `"images/"` or `"videos/"` in the tag `"resourceType"` in the plugin. Is it possible to use them both?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a string, apparently you can't. From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-cloudinary):

> This is the type of file. Possible values: image, raw, video. Note:
> Use the video resource type for all video resources as well as for
> audio files, such as .mp3.

What you can try is to create two instances of the `gatsby-source-cloudinary`, one for each type of asset:

```
  {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-cloudinary`,
      options: {
        cloudName: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
        apiKey: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
        apiSecret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
        resourceType: `image`,
        prefix: `gatsby-source-cloudinary/images` 
      }
    }

  {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-cloudinary`,
      options: {
        cloudName: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
        apiKey: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
        apiSecret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
        resourceType: `video`,
        prefix: `gatsby-source-cloudinary/video` 
      }
    }
```